# How to echo two arrays without removing duplicates?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to display data with two different arrays but without removing their duplicate at least.

These are the data in my database that I am working with, I did explode to separate the values and store it into an array.

| kilos | warehouse_quantity | store_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25.20.15 | 10.5.10 | 0.3.10 |

```php
<?php
$store = explode('.', $data->store_quantity);
$kilos = explode('.', $data->kilos);

$arr_of_store = array();
$arr_of_kilos = array();

foreach($store as $store){
    $arr_of_store[] = $store;
}

foreach($kilos as $kilos){
    $arr_of_kilos[] = $kilos;
}

echo "Stacks in store: ";

$array_together = array_combine($arr_of_store,$arr_of_kilos);
foreach($array_together as $arr_of_store => $arr_of_kilos){
    echo $arr_of_store.' sacks of '.$arr_of_kilos.'kg'.'<br>';
}

echo "<br>";
echo "Stacks in warehouse: ";

$warehouse = explode('.', $data->warehouse_quantity);
$kilos2 = explode('.', $data->kilos);

$arr_of_ware = array();
$arr_of_kilos2 = array();

foreach($warehouse as $warehouse){
    $arr_of_ware[] = $warehouse;
}

foreach($kilos2 as $kilos2){
    $arr_of_kilos2[] = $kilos2;
}

$array_together2 = array_combine($arr_of_ware,$arr_of_kilos2);

foreach($array_together2 as $arr_of_ware => $arr_of_kilos2){
    echo $arr_of_ware.' sacks of '.$arr_of_kilos2.'kg'.'<br>';
}

?>
```

My desired output is

```
Stacks in store: 
0 sacks of 25kg
3 sacks of 20kg
10 sacks of 15kg

Stacks in warehouse: 
10 sacks of 25kg
5 sacks of 20kg
10 sacks of 15kg
```

But what I get is this

```
Stacks in store: 
0 sacks of 25kg
3 sacks of 20kg
10 sacks of 15kg

Stacks in warehouse: 
10 sacks of 15kg
5 sacks of 20kg
```

I tried concat() based on what I found in the internet stating that It can be used to display two arrays without removing duplicate but I receive an error instead where **Call to undefined function concat()**. What should I do to display the desired output?

Comment: `foreach ($store as $store)` is not going to work. Your iterating variable is the same as your array. You'd need something like `$stores as $store`. Same goes for `$kilos`

Comment: Are you truly using Laravel? If that is the case, where are you using `echo`? You should NEVER use that

Comment: Change `$store = explode('.', $data->store_quantity);` by `$arr_of_store = explode('.', $data->store_quantity); ` because `explode` always return an array. Then i think you `array_combine` two cells with the same key.

Comment: Tysm for pointing that out @JustCarty It's how the tutorial vids I'm watching does it, but I'll make sure to do that from now on.

Comment: Tysm @matiaslauriti for telling. I created **<?php ?>** inside my blade file instead of **@php** for creating a variables and display it through echo. I'm not really familiar with Laravel that much and the codes I'm trying to follow are all php, can't seem to find similar ones doing it inside their blade file so I did it like that.

Comment: Tysm @piferrari for pointing that out because the video that I watched didn't explain about returning the data without duplicate until I encountered it in doing one and tried to use ``concat()``  that I had read but also didn't work in displaying the desired output

Comment: @NeedHalp in Laravel you don't php functions, nor use `echo` on a blade view/file... you use `{{ }}`... al the processing you are using should be done by either the controller and just sharing the data to the view, or using `@foreach` or anything similar, use blade directives, not PHP...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
//Simulate your data
$data = new stdClass();
$data->kilos = '25.20.15';
$data->warehouse_quantity = '10.5.10';
$data->store_quantity = '0.3.10';
//var_dump($data);

function StacksInStore($datax) {
    echo 'Stacks in store: ';
    $kilos = explode('.',$datax->kilos);
    $store_quantity = explode('.',$datax->store_quantity);
    for($i=0;$i<count($store_quantity);$i++) {
    echo '<br/>'.$store_quantity[$i].' sacks of '.$kilos[$i].'kg';
    }
}
function StacksInWarehouse($datax) {
    echo 'Stacks in warehouse:  ';
    $kilos = explode('.',$datax->kilos);
    $warehouse_quantity = explode('.',$datax->warehouse_quantity);
    for($i=0;$i<count($warehouse_quantity);$i++) {
    echo '<br/>'.$warehouse_quantity[$i].' sacks of '.$kilos[$i].'kg';
    }
}

/*
 * Stacks in store: 
0 sacks of 25kg
3 sacks of 20kg
10 sacks of 15kg

Stacks in warehouse: 
10 sacks of 25kg
5 sacks of 20kg
10 sacks of 15kg
 * 
 */
StacksInStore($data);
echo '<br/><hr/><br/>';
StacksInWarehouse($data);
```

[how to video](https://youtu.be/R3k44OQ8HpI)

Comment: For anyone having this issue in the future, have in mind that you are printing stuff on a blade view using `echo`, you have php functions inside a blade view, etc. when using Laravel. This fixes the issue, but is for sure not a good solution...